# Can my server integrate Firebase Authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

So I'm all new to Firebase and took a look at the features they offer. I'm planning to build a react-native app that will access the Firebase API through a Node.js server I will create.

What I'll need is the realtime database, cloud messaging, storage and authentication (It'll be some sort of messenger).

Because the mobile apps won't be written in Swift or Java, I'm confused as to whether things will/should happen in the react-native app using the Firebase npm package, or using a Node.js server in between that does everything.

Let's say I want to use cloud messaging to send notifications to people programmatically. It's obvious this has to happen on a server. However, if the authentication happens in the react-native app using the npm package, how can my server know if the user is authenticated?

You might see I don't have a clue how to organise things here. I mentioned the 4 things I need to do, and that I'll build react-native apps as the front end.

How would you do it? Is a server required at all, and if yes, could it do everything and just "forward" actions from the apps to Firebase, including the authentication part?

Thanks

Comment: Firebase is meant to be used from the client straight to Firebase, not through your server. If you are using a server between Firebase and the client, you will be losing the best stuff Firebase has to offer.

Comment: In a scenario like yours, most developers use Firebase as the middle layer between the app and the server-side business logic. See this (old, but still relevant) blog post on Firebase application architectures: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html